# "Cursor is closed" error - when trying to execute an Oracle SP using JDBC

Tags: oracle, exception, jdbc, cursor

The Oracle version of our database is 10g.

The stored procedure selects all the elements in a table and returns a REF CURSOR type as follows:
create or replace

```
PROCEDURE S_S_TEST( 
  test_OUT OUT OAS_TYPES.REFCURSOR
) 
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN test_OUT FOR      
      SELECT *
      FROM table_p;
   CLOSE test_OUT;
END S_S_TEST;
```

When this stored procedure is executed in JAVA the following exception is obtained-

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cursor is closed. at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CResultSetAccessor.getCursor(T4CResultSetAccessor.java:323) at oracle.jdbc.driver.ResultSetAccessor.getObject(ResultSetAccessor.java:85) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.getObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:1401) at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcCallableStatement.getObject(WSJdbcCallableStatement.java:443)
```

I am trying to understand what the error is and how it could be fixed. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client calling the stored procedure is responsible for closing the cursor.  Please remove the code:
CLOSE test_OUT;

The client closes it.  In this case the client is the JDBC program that calls the stored procedure.